# Using indirect function to reference another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to summerise daily inventory in a new wkb, by referencing another wkb(source) which contains sheets/tabs named in date order(such as 01.04.14, 02.04.14 etc). On each of the source sheets/tabs, the total daily figure is in cell D23. On the destination sheet, I've labelled the columns 1 , 2, 3.....to represent each day and the months on the rows.

I tried using the indirect function

```
=INDIRECT("'X:\WorkbookDirectory\["&TEXT($A2,"MMM-YY")&".xlsx]"&TEXT(B$1,"DD.MM.YY")&"'!$F$23")
```

however, it couldn't copy across the sheets/tabs. Any ideas as how I could fix this with a VBA code?

Comment: No, it will not be opened.